# Why won't shutter release when in flash mode?

Tags: flash

I bought a used Nikon D3100 and cannot get the shutter to release in flash mode. The camera works great as long as it is not calling for flash. Not sure what to try or do.

Comment: I don't know the camera well enough to be sure of this, but it may be that the camera is set to wait until the flash is fully charged.  If something is preventing the flash from indicating it has a charge, it would then not fire.  If your camera does this, it should be a setting somewhere, but I don't know where it would be.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of, isn't related to the flash, but to the "confirm focus before shutter release" setting. My logic being you're using flash in a dark environment without an AF lock possibly.

Comment: Everything seems to be as it should be. I cannot get it to fire at all. I have tried every setting I cn find. Did all the resets and still no luck. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the Godox flash I attached to my d7500. It turns out that the contacts on both the flash and the hot shoe were dirty enough to cause a problem.  A few seconds of light burnishing with some very fine steel wool solved it--taking care to blow away the residual dust and debris. I wouldn't do this every day, but if you leave the flash mounted for long periods, it may be necessary once in a great while.  The before and after difference wasn't visible to me, but the flash started working normally after the "treatment."====

Answer (score 0):

Auto focus is the culprit here. switch to Manual focus and the shutter will fire :)

Comment: The shutter will fire as long as it is not calling for flash. When the flash pops up the shutter will not release. Maybe the flash has gone bad ??